# Sound card and speakers doesn't show on Asus Transformer T103H

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have an Asus Transformer T103H and can't get the internal speakers to work.

When I type `cat /proc/asound/cards`, only one sound card is shown, which is `Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio`. I expect that there should be an entry for the internal sound card.

`aplay -l` shows 3 devices, all for the same sound card mentioned above.

In GNOME Settings/Sound, it only shows one entry: `Dummy Output`

How can I get linux to detect the internal sound card and speakers on the Asus Transformer Mini T103H?

Comment: The *Intel® Cherry Trail Quad-Core Processor* still has very poor support in Linux. Try the latest Ubuntu release for better results (hopefully).

Comment: I am on the latest release - everything except the sound works

Comment: There's probably no solution.

Comment: here [link](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/sound-not-working-asus-t103/51008) he got `bytchtnocodec` as Device 0

Comment: The thread was closed with no solution.

Comment: please post full output response of `aplay -l`. use alsa-info.sh script to get more information on ALSA and post link to it here. The Manjaro forum discussion link did not get to a solution, but did link onward to bugzilla report that was closed as solved with solution on github

Comment: The github solution worked

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was actually very easy:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall alsa-ucm-conf

echo "options snd-intel-dspcfg dsp_driver=2" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

[Reference: github sof project issue](https://github.com/thesofproject/sof/issues/3868)